# How to multiply the float element of a matrix by an integer?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have tried code below to multiply float element of matrix `a` which is less then one by any integer but it's not working on the other hand it is working properly for the matrix whose element is not a float i.e if you define matix `a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)` then it's working.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)

print(a)
print('new matrix')
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite']):
  if x in range(0,1):
    x[...] = 100*x
print(a)
```

Comment: Is this your code? Because `x[...]` - here x is a float, not something indexable here?

Comment: `range(0,1)` means a range of integers - from inclusive to exclusive, so here `if` hits literally only when x=0. If you want x to be between 0 and 1, you have to just do `0 <= x < 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [130]: a = np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)                                                          
In [131]: a                                                                                            
Out[131]: 
array([[0.   , 0.125, 0.25 ],
       [0.375, 0.5  , 0.625],
       [0.75 , 0.875, 1.   ]])
```

I don't usually recommend using `nditer` to iterate through an array.  It's hard to use right, and rarely, if ever, improves speed.  I'm not sure who or what is prompting people to use it.  Its docs could use a stronger speed disclaimer.

Anyways, lets examine what's happening.

```
In [136]: for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite']): 
     ...:   print(type(x), x, x.shape)   
     ...:   if x in range(0,1): 
     ...:     x[...] = 100*x 
     ...:     print('mul') 
     ...:                                                                                              
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.0 ()
mul
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.125 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.25 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.375 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.5 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.625 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.75 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.875 ()
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 1.0 ()
```

`nditer` runs through every element of the array (not rows), producing a 0d view each time (shape `()`).  Only one of those elements is 0, so it multiplies by 100.  None of the others are in `range(0,1)`  (Only `0 in range(0,1)`, everything else is `False`).

So the iteration is work, at least as coded, if not as you intend.

`a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)` doesn't change anything.  Only the 0 is `in range(0,1)`,

===

Change the `if` test:

```
In [146]: a = np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)                                                          
In [147]: a                                                                                            
Out[147]: 
array([[0.   , 0.125, 0.25 ],
       [0.375, 0.5  , 0.625],
       [0.75 , 0.875, 1.   ]])
In [148]: for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite']):  
     ...:   if x<1: 
     ...:     x[...] = 100*x 
     ...:     print('mul') 
     ...:                                                                                              
mul
...
mul
In [149]: a                                                                                            
Out[149]: 
array([[ 0. , 12.5, 25. ],
       [37.5, 50. , 62.5],
       [75. , 87.5,  1. ]])
```

An alternative to `nditer` is a `flat` iteration.  In some ways that's messier since it requires a `enumerate` if we want to modify original values:

```
In [150]: a = np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)                                                          
In [151]: for i,v in enumerate(a.flat): 
     ...:     if v<1: 
     ...:         a.flat[i] *= 100 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [152]: a                                                                                            
Out[152]: 
array([[ 0. , 12.5, 25. ],
       [37.5, 50. , 62.5],
       [75. , 87.5,  1. ]])
```

But despite some claims in the `nditer` docs, it isn't faster:

```
In [153]: %%timeit a=np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3) 
     ...: for i,v in enumerate(a.flat): 
     ...:     if v<1: 
     ...:         a.flat[i] *= 100 
5.4 µs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [154]:                                                                                              
In [154]: %%timeit a=np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3) 
     ...: for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite']):  
     ...:   if x<1: 
     ...:     x[...] = 100*x 
34.4 µs ± 108 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

===

But normally you shouldn't be iterating on an array.  A whole-array, **vectorized**, approach is:

```
In [157]: mask = a<1                                                                                   
In [158]: mask                                                                                         
Out[158]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
In [159]: a[mask] *= 100                                                                               
In [160]: a                                                                                            
Out[160]: 
array([[ 0. , 12.5, 25. ],
       [37.5, 50. , 62.5],
       [75. , 87.5,  1. ]])
In [161]: %%timeit a=np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3) 
     ...: a[a<1] *= 100                                                                                               
12.5 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Ouch! that's slower than the flat enumerate - for this small example.  For a much larger `a` this will do much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the range "manually" in a boolean filter to multiply only the elements you are targeting:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0,1,9).reshape(3,3)

print(a)
print('new matrix')
a[(a>0) & (a<1)] *= 100
print(a)

[[0.    0.125 0.25 ]
 [0.375 0.5   0.625]
 [0.75  0.875 1.   ]]
new matrix
[[ 0.  12.5 25. ]
 [37.5 50.  62.5]
 [75.  87.5  1. ]]
```

*note that your linear space will only ever generate 1 value that is outside of the range (the last one) so you might as well multiply everything and reassign the last value to 1*